Opengl Render texture unnormal
I tried an OpenGL cube texture rendering exampl.But the texture rendered unnormally.Left is the rendered result, right is the original picture:

The code is:
app::Shader cube_shader{ "Cube" };
float vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         ... ...
};
unsigned int cube_VAO, cube_VBO, cube_texture;
//vao,vbo id generate and bind buffer data code
...
glGenTextures(1, &cube_texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, cube_texture);
...
unsigned char* data = stbi_load(pic_path.c_str(), &width, &height, &nrChannels, 0);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

cube_shader.load();
cube_shader.setInt("texture1", 0);

//event loop code 
    glClearColor(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, cube_texture);
    cube_shader.load();
    //set the model,view, projection matrix
    ...
    glBindVertexArray(cube_VAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

    glfwSwapBuffers(mainWindow);
    glfwPollEvents();

The vertex shader code:
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

out vec2 TexCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model*vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    //gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
    TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);
}

the fragment shader code:
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;
uniform sampler2D texture1;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(texture1, TexCoord);
}

The texture using the picture does not rendered normally, so why, is there any bugs in the code?

Pass 4 as the last parameter to stbi_load, since you expect the texture to always be RGBA and ignore nrChannels.

@HolyBlackCat Great!It works!Thank you very much!
